# RestController asking username and password in Spring JAVA project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring and Java applications.
I exposed a controller in my app and upon running the service, when I make a call to that controller,

it asks a username and password.

Is there any way to disable it? as I have not set or desire to set any sort of authentication.

Comment: If you have spring-security setup and the method is secured, then it will obviously ask for username and password. You might want to remove '@PreAuthorize' or '@Secured' annotation for those methods if you want. But not recommended if they are accessing secured resources.

Comment: I have not added these annotations ???

Comment: Post relevant code, how can we magically guess whats the problem.

Comment: maybe you can use permitAll in your security config, by `http
   .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest().permitAll()`

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: You should tell how you have configured spring-security. Through xml or java config or trough some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove any spring security related libraries from your classpath. 
For me, removing the 'spring-boot-starter-security' from my dependencies helped.

```
    dependencies {
    //compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security' //Remove this
}
```